# How create collectionview header like instagram tags searching one?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, instagram

Can anyone help me how this header can be implemented? Especially how it works during scrolling? Seems that when I scroll to bottom this header is pushed up like a cell, but when I scroll to top it's static and looks like a view over collection view.
Photos 
1) [INITIAL STATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHQWX.jpg)

2) [SCROLL TO TOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77aKu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the header isn't part of the collection view at all, but a sibling, i.e. the both share the same superview.

The collection view is given a large content inset at the top to make room for the header. Then, as the collection view scrolls, the scroll events are captured via delegate method and used to shrink or expand the header to make it appear as if it's sliding beneath the navBar.

(For reasons that have to do with the navBar translucency, it's not actually pushed under the navBar, but that's not immediately relevant to this question)